# YUV Raw frames to video stream

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding

Im trying to stream raw YUV frames in an array generated in a C++ program to video using FFPEG. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Using FFMPEG libraries or ffmpeg executable? In the latter case, are the frames stored as separate files on disk, or one file, or will be piped via standard input?

Comment: they are passed as lists containing the values of the image. I guess piped then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stream piped YUV420 planar frames to RTMP try e.g.

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -c:v rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i - -c:v libx264 -f flv rtmp:///live/myStream.sdp
```